# PasswordPropertyText vs DataType(DataType.Password) attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, data-annotations, .net-attributes

What exactly is the difference between these two .NET [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/):

- `[PasswordPropertyText]` => [PasswordPropertyTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.passwordpropertytextattribute)
- `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` => [DataTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute) with a [DataType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.datatype) of value [`DataType.Password`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype)

`Password` property in my `ViewModel` that I have decorated with both attributes:

```csharp
[PasswordPropertyText(true)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Password field in my `View`:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

> Indicates that an object's text representation is obscured by characters such as asterisks.

This is the definition of the [`PasswordPropertyTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.passwordpropertytextattribute#definition), but it's actually the `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` attribute that fulfills that role, the `[PasswordPropertyText(true)]` attribute doesn't render the password field properly - the `input` tag  should have a `type="password"` attribute instead of `type="text"`.

HTML code generated when only `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` is applied:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="password" id="Password" name="Password">
```

HTML code generated when only `[PasswordPropertyText(true)]` is applied:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="Password" name="Password" value="">
```

HTML code generated when both `[DataType(DataType.Password)]` and `[PasswordPropertyText(true)]` are applied:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="password" id="Password" name="Password">
```

I am currently confused whether or not I am applying the `[PasswordPropertyText(true)]` attribute properly, and what is its purpose after all, compared to `[DataType(DataType.Password)]`.

Comment: Now that I am re-reading the docs more carefully, I am getting the impression that `PasswordPropertyTextAttribute` isn't used in `ASP.NET` projects, but in `Windows.Forms` ones instead...am I wrong?

Comment: From what the docs indicate I'd guess so, yes.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for reassuring me, unfortunately the docs aren't always explicit.